# blueman config file location

Tags: blueman

When I login to X, I get a message from `blueman` saying that the `~/Downloads` directory doesn't exist, and to run `blueman-services` to change it.

However the options in the GUI to change the folder are greyed out.

Is there a way to change the download directory in a configuration file?

Answer (score 6):

`blueman` doesn't use a config file, instead using `dconf`.

I used `dconf-editor` and found the setting at:

```
/org/blueman/transfer/shared-path
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change the host name, this will resolve the issue.

e.g. raspberry.pi to just raspberry

This corrected my issue on Debian after adding a new user and deleting the pi account

Comment: Cloud you provide infrormation why this works? `blueman` is bluetooth manager, and I can't get why changing the host name would resolve the issue.